# How to get matrix value returned by MATLAB function in C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I am trying to call a MATLAB function in C#. I was successful in running a simple example where one value was returned, but I want to return a vector and a matrix. How can I do that?

```
// Create the MATLAB instance 
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

// Change to the directory where the function is located 
matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\MATLABcodevisualstudio");

// Define the output 
object result = null;

// Call the MATLAB function myfunc
matlab.Feval("test", 2 , out result, 3.14, 42.0,"world");

// double[,] arr = (double[,])((MWNumericArray)result).ToArray(MWArrayComponent.Real); // if i use this it returns error 

// Display result 
object[] res = result as object[];
```

Now the result is returned in `object result` (`double[,]`). I want to take the value from this double array and use them for other computations and write them to a .csv file. However, when I tried

```
 double[,] arr = (double[,])((MWNumericArray)result).ToArray(MWArrayComponent.Real);
```

It gave an error

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
'System.Object[]' to type
'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWNumericArray'.
```

How can I access and bring the value in returned object?